# Complex .Net Core Tag Helpers that share a same model (independent from @Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Using .Net Framework's helper I could do stuff like this:

```
@CustomHelper.Table(List<MyModel>).Column(x => x.prop1).Column(x => x.prop1.mySubProp);
```

Where I could access propertys for "MyModel" using lambda expressions in order to generate complex html structures or tables based on those porperties.

Is it possible to do something similar in .Net Core so I can use these kind of structures?

```
<my-helper model="@List<MyType>">
  <my-sub-helper property="@(x => x.myProp1)"><\my-sub-helper>
  <my-sub-helper property="@(x => x.myProp1.mySubProp)"><\my-sub-helper>
<\my-helper>
```

Since I don't have access to Generic Type tagHelpers I haven't managed to do something like that. Right now what I've got is something like this:

```
<my-helper model="@Model.List"> //Which is a List<MyType>
  <my-sub-helper property="myProp1"><\my-sub-helper> //Which are properties of MyType.
  <my-sub-helper property="myProp1.mySubProp"><\my-sub-helper>
<\my-helper>
```

Where I'm using strings to capture "MyType"'s property names but obviously I cannot use intellisense if I use this method.

I've also tried capturing the property names using model expressions so the code in the front end looks like this.

```
<my-helper model="@List<MyType>">
  <my-sub-helper property="@Model.List.firstOrDefault().myProp1"><\my-sub-helper>
  <my-sub-helper property="@Model.List.firstOrDefault().myProp1.mySubProp"><\my-sub-helper>
<\my-helper>
```

But I didn't manage to capture the whole route to "mySubProp" which would be a string similar to "myProp1.mySubProp".

Any ideas on how to implement this kind of stuff cleanly?